# How to add background image to jframe confused

Tags: java, swing, jframe, background-image, imageicon

How can I can add a background image to my JFrame and where should U add the code?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon.*;
import javax.swing.*; //import java swing to use the Jframe etc

public class MathQuiz extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

JCheckBox answer1 = new JCheckBox(); //checkbozx for answer 1
JCheckBox answer2 = new JCheckBox(); //checkbozx for answer 2
JCheckBox answer3 = new JCheckBox(); //checkbozx for answer 3
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();//text area for question
JButton exit = new JButton(); // button to exit quiz
JButton calculator = new JButton(); // button to open calculator
JLabel image = new JLabel(); //adds background image

// Some names which will be associated with numbers.
int answer;
int questionnumber;


/**
   * This bit of code starts the process of showing the window.
**/
public MathQuiz()
{
    // Drop down to the code labeled 'initComponents' below.

    try {
        initComponents();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

}


/**
 * This bit of code is the first bit that's run.
**/
static public void main(String[] args)
{
    MathQuiz frame = new MathQuiz(); 
    // The following code puts the Window on your screen.

    frame.setVisible(true); //allows the jframe to be visible
    frame.showQuestion(1);//shows the first question
    frame.setSize(370, 350);//sets the size of the frame

}

/**
 * This bit of code sets up how the Window looks.
**/
public void initComponents() throws Exception
{
```

edits the checkboxes for the answers

```
    answer1.setSize(new Dimension(80, 20)); //set size of answer 1 checkbox
    answer1.setVisible(true); //sets visible to answer 1 checkbox
    answer1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(80, 20)); 
    answer1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 20)); 
    answer1.setLocation(new Point(10, 180)); //set location answer 1 checkbox


    answer2.setSize(new Dimension(80, 20)); //set size of answer 2 checkbox
    answer2.setVisible(true);//sets visible to answer 2 checkbox
    answer2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
    answer2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
    answer2.setLocation(new Point(10, 210)); //set location answer 2 checkbox

    answer3.setSize(new Dimension(80, 20)); //set size of answer 3 checkbox
    answer3.setVisible(true);//sets visible to answer 3 checkbox
    answer3.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
    answer3.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
    answer3.setLocation(new Point(10, 240)); //set location answer 3 checkbox
```

code to edit the text area on the JFrame

```
    textArea.setSize(new Dimension(340, 80)); //set size of text ares
    textArea.setLineWrap(true); 
    textArea.setVisible(true); //sets visible to text area
    textArea.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 140)); //set maximum size of text area
    textArea.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 140)); //set minimum size of text area
    textArea.setLocation(new Point(10, 20)); //set location of text area
    textArea.setEditable(false);
```

code to edit the exit button on the JFrame

```
    exit.setSize(new Dimension(104, 40)); //set size of button
    exit.setVisible(true); //sets visible to button
    exit.setLocation(new Point(230, 180)); //set location of button
    exit.setText("Exit");
```

code to edit the exit button on the JFrame

```
    calculator.setSize(new Dimension(104, 40)); //set size of button
    calculator.setVisible(true); //sets visible to button
    calculator.setLocation(new Point(230, 230)); //set location of button
    calculator.setText("Calculator");

    image.setIcon(new ImageIcon("maths"));
    image.setVisible(true);
```

This sets up the size of the Window and adds the swing utilities to the

```
    setSize(new Dimension(430, 292));
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setTitle("Multiple Choice Math Quiz!");
    setLocation(new Point(200, 200));
    getContentPane().add(answer1);
    getContentPane().add(answer2);
    getContentPane().add(answer3);
    getContentPane().add(textArea);
    getContentPane().add(exit);
    getContentPane().add(calculator);
```

Comment: To with, don't use null layouts, there more work and trouble then they are worth. A simple solution would be to use a JLabel, set its icon property to the background image you want to use, set its layout manager appropriately, and add the rest if your components to it. Search SO for "Swing frame background", there are plenty of examples...

Comment: All you have to do is look under the "Related" heading on the right side of this page to find some other question on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You do it properly by adding an image to a `JLabel` which you add in turn to the `JFrame`.

As highlighted in the comments, the problem lies in the `Null` layout you use.

Try another [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).